# How to convert string representation list with mixed values to a list?

Tags: python, pandas

How do can I convert a string that contains values that are both strings and numeric, given that the string within the list is not in quotes?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['[2, A]', '[5, BC]']})

print(df)

     col_1
0   [2, A]
1  [5, BC]

col_1    [2, A]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

My aim is to use the list in another function, so I tried to transform the string with built-in functions such as eval() or ast.literal_eval(), however in both cases I need to add quotes around the strings, so it is "A" and "BC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use a regex to add quotes around the potential strings (here I used letters + underscore), then use `literal_eval` (for some reason I have an error with `pd.eval`)

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['col_1'].str.replace(r'([a-zA-Z_]+)', r'"\1"', regex=True).apply(literal_eval)
```

output (lists):

```
0     [2, A]
1    [5, BC]
```

Comment: How does the repl parameter work `r'"\1"'`? I especially don't understand what's the `\1` within the quotes.

Comment: the `\1` is a callback of the expression that was captured by the parentheses in the regex (i.e., your word), this means capture a letter/underscore only word and replace it with itself surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It is already a string and If the data is going to be in a **certain format-**

```
df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1].rstrip(']'))
```

Comment: I think the goal is to have the correct types (2-> int, A -> str)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be a list:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['[2, A]', '[5, BC]']})
print(df)

a = df["col_1"].to_list()
actual_list = [[int(i.split(",")[0][1:]), str(i.split(",")[1][1:-1])] for i in a]
actual_list
```

Output:

```
[[2, 'A'], [5, 'BC']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to convert string representation list to list of strings, you can use [`str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) together with [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), as follows:

```
df['col_1'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s*')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df['col_1'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s*').to_dict())

{0: ['2', 'A'], 1: ['5', 'BC']}
```

If you further want to convert the strings of numeric values to numbers, you can further use [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), as follows:

```
df['col_1'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s*').apply(lambda x: [pd.to_numeric(y, errors='ignore') for y in x])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df['col_1'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s*').apply(lambda x: [pd.to_numeric(y, errors='ignore') for y in x]).to_dict())

{0: [2, 'A'], 1: [5, 'BC']}           # 2, 5 are numbers instead of strings
```